# Maven2: use ${basedir} in jar path

Tags: java, maven-2

I am using an external, proprietary jar in my project.  When I hard-code the path as follows in my pom.xml, it works fine:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
  <version>5.2</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <type>jar</type>
  <systemPath>D:\workspace\myproj\external\companyname\lib\proprietary_api.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

However, when I try to use the ${basedir} variable, maven can't find the jar:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
  <version>5.2</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <type>jar</type>
  <systemPath>${basedir}\external\companyname\lib\proprietary_api.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

The pom is located in D:\workspace\myproj

This also needs to be cross-platform compatible (dev on Windows, deploy on Linux).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It is wrong to use system scope for your proprietary JARs. You should deploy or install it into the local/central repository.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this will help, but try using forward (`/`) instead of backward (`\`) slashes. Also, try running it with `mvn -e` and `mvn -X` (the latter will produce a **lot** of debugging lines) - this might help you pinpoint the problem.

Here's an example:

- http://jmonkeyengine.org/groups/contribution-depot-jme3/forum/topic/maven-2-pomxml

of using `${basedir}` in the same way you want.

Btw, why don't you `mvn install:install-file` the dependency instead of using `systemPath`? See:

- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 3):

In order to be cross-platform compatible use ${file.separator} instead of the slashes.. 
so that will automatically convert to OS specified format

Answer (score 0):

1. Use forward slashes in the path.
2. The ${basedir} placeholder is extrapolated **only once** per Maven run. If this project is not the topmost project in your project hierarchy, then ${basedir} will be extrapolated to the location of the topmost project (i.e. the project where Maven started), not the current project.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work both on windows and linux, you have to start using profiles. In that way, a particular profile will get activated based on the OS and the build will become portable.

In each profile, you can define a property called jarPath (just an example) and refer that property in your dependency.

[Maven Profiles Introduction](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Look into the OS tag and configuration tag of the profile. Make sure your build are always portable and less manual steps needs to be done.involved.